# Syntax confusion (do block)

Tags: haskell, syntax, indentation

Sorry for a poor title, feel free to edit. I can't understand what the problem is, so it might be altogether wrong. Below is the code (this is after I've done like a hundred of permutations and different sequences of let-do-if and tabulation, and I'm exhausted):

```
-- The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression
numberOfGoods :: IO String
numberOfGoods = do putStrLn "Enter year (2000-2012):\n"
                   let intYear = readYear 
                   in if (intYear < 2000 || intYear > 2012)
                         then error "Year must be withing range: 2000-2012" 
                         else
                                c <- readIORef connection
                                [Only i] <- query_ c ("select count('*')" ++
                                         "from table" ++
                                         "where ((acquisition_date <= " ++
                                         (formatDate intYear) ++
                                         ") and ((sale_date is null) or " ++
                                         "(sale_date < " ++
                                         (formatDate intYear) ++ ")))")
                                return i

readYear :: Integer
readYear = do
           year <- getLine
           read year :: Integer
```

Something that would meant to be so simple... I still don't understand what is wrong with the code above. Please, if you could kindly explain the source of the error, that would be great.
I did read about do, let-in and if-then-else, and I don't see any errors here from what I could understand from the manual.

Ideally, if there are alternatives, I would like very much to reduce the amount of the wasted white space on the left.

Thank you.

Comment: Being defined using IO, `readYear` can't possibly be an Integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readYear` is not an `Integer`, it's an `IO` action that can be run to read input and convert the input to an integer -- in other words, `IO Integer`. And as it's an `IO` action, you'll need a `return` to use whatever `read year` as result of `getYear`. That is:

```
getYear :: IO Integer
getYear = do year <- getLine
             return (read year)
```

This also means you use it like `intYear <- readYear` instead of using `let` (well, you could, but you'd store the IO action instead of running it, and the type of `intYear` would be wrong). That is:

```
numberOfGoods :: IO String
numberOfGoods = do putStrLn "Enter year (2000-2012):\n"
                   intYear <- readYear
                   ...
```

`do` does not extend over `if`, rather you need to start again with `do` if you want a sequence of actions in the `then` or `else` branch. That is:

```
                     else
                            c <- readIORef connection
                            ...
                            return i
```

should be roughly:

```
                     else do c <- readIORef connection
                             ...
                             return i
```

As for reducing whitespace, consider pushing the validation logic into `readYear`. Implementing this is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

As an aside, you don't need `in` when using `let` in a `do` block (but only there!), you can simply state:

```
do do_something
   let val = pure_compuation
   something_else_using val
```

Comment: @wvxvw Generally, you *always* need `do`, unless it's a single expression (`do error "..."` has redundancy) or you're already immediately inside a `do` block. So `let`, `where`, etc. all need a `do` in general. It may make more sense when you understand what `do` notation desugars to (but for that you need to really understand monads - well, one more reason to ^^). An the `let` "shortcut" is only possibly when immediately inside a `do` block - it's just a special piece of syntactic sugar for that specific purpose.

Comment: @wvxvw never using `do` is hardly appropriate... I wrote out how you function looks without its sugar, and you'll agree it's not particularly handsome. `do` is actually really helpful and causes hardly any trouble, it's just a bit confusing as long as one hasn't properly grasped the underlying monad structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new `do` for every block of monadic functions: simply writing functions in a row has no meaning, regardless of whether they're monadic or pure. And everything where the value comes from the `IO` monad must itself give its return value in the monad.

```
numberOfGoods :: IO String
numberOfGoods = do putStrLn "Enter year (2000-2012):\n"  -- why extra '\n'?
                   intYear <- readYear   -- readYear expects user input <- must be monadic
                   if (intYear < 2000 || intYear > 2012)
                         then error "Year must be withing range: 2000-2012" 
                         else do
                                c <- readIORef connection
                                [Only i] <- query_ c ("select count('*')" ++
                                         "from table" ++
                                         "where ((acquisition_date <= " ++
                                         (formatDate intYear) ++
                                         ") and ((sale_date is null) or " ++
                                         "(sale_date < " ++
                                         (formatDate intYear) ++ ")))")
                                return i

readYear :: IO Integer
readYear = do
           year <- getLine
           return $ read year :: Integer
```

---

Why is an extra `do` needed...

Well, the thing with `do` in Haskell is that it's really just syntactic sugar. Let's simplify your function a little

```
nOG :: IO String
nOG = do putStrLn "Prompt"
         someInput <- inputSth
         if condition someInput
             then error "Bloap" 
             else do c <- inputSthElse
                     [only] <- query_ c
                     return only
```

what this actually means is

```
nOG :: IO String
nOG = putStrLn "Prompt"
        >> inputSth
           >>= (\someInput ->
                  if condition someInput
                    then error "Bloap" 
                    else inputSthElse
                             >>= (\s -> query_ c
                                          >>= (\[only] -> return only )
                                 )
               )
```

Where you should be able to see that `if` behaves in exactly the same way as it does in a pure functional expression like `shade (r,g,b) = if g>r && g>b then "greenish" else "purpleish"`. It doesn't in any way "know" about all the `IO` monad stuff going on around it, so it can't infer that there should again be a `do` block in one of its branches.

Comment: do is not a block, it's an expression. The <- syntax is only allowed in do expressions. The outer do sees 3 subexpressions: the print, the inputSth and the if, but it can't look inside the if. As told before, the if itself does not care if there is a do expression in the else, or a list comprehension, or whatever - as long as it is syntactically a single expression. `a <- foo  b <- bar  return a` is not a single expression, it is no expression at all because of the <-