# Overloaded strings in simple-mysql

Tags: haskell, syntax, casting, literals

This is a follow up question to this one: [Syntax confusion (do block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573388/syntax-confusion-do-block) So, please see it for more information and the original code. After I've been kindly helped, I've discovered yet another problem, which I suspect to be caused by "overloaded strings" whatever that means.

It looks like the simple-mysql library does something to string literal, so that they are understood by the parser to be of type `Query`. This is also what their examples demonstrate. However, all examples use unrealistically short queries, where you don't need to wrap the code. I do need to wrap it, and string concatenation causes the resulting string to not to be recognized as of type `Query`. Why did anyone decide that this kind of approach will be useful is beyond my comprehension, I just want to be done with this assignment...

So, please, if you happen to know, kindly advise what to do / how can I have string converted to query.

The problematic code and the error are shown below:

```
-- Couldn't match expected type `Query' against inferred type `[a]'
-- In the expression:
--       "select count('*')"
--     ++  "from table"
--       ++  "where ((acquisition_date <= ?)"
--         ++  "and ((sale_date is null) or " ++ "(sale_date < ?)))"
-- In the definition of `countGoodsQuery':
--     countGoodsQuery = "select count('*')"
--                     ++  "from table"
--                       ++  "where ((acquisition_date <= ?)"
--                         ++  "and ((sale_date is null) or " ++ "(sale_date < ?)))"

countGoodsQuery :: Query
countGoodsQuery = "select count('*')" ++
                  "from table" ++
                  "where ((acquisition_date <= ?)" ++
                  "and ((sale_date is null) or " ++
                  "(sale_date < ?)))"
```

Comment: Since your type error doesn't have anything to do with the multi-line query issue, you should probably ask about that in a separate question.

Comment: You should have another look at the documentation. `query_` is for queries that don't take parameters. Replace it with `query` and it should work (I think).

Comment: No problem :) I took the liberty of rolling back your edit. If you still have questions about the other error, just post a new question. Less messy that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a string literal across multiple lines by adding a backslash at the end of the line, and another backslash where the string should continue, so you can write your example like this:

```
countGoodsQuery :: Query
countGoodsQuery = "select count('*')\
                  \from table\
                  \where ((acquisition_date <= ?)\
                  \and ((sale_date is null) or \
                  \(sale_date < ?)))"
```

Answer (score 1):

I gather you already got past it, but to more completely answer your question:

`mysql-simple` gives `Query` an instance for the `IsString` typeclass.  When you type a string literal in a file, it'll use the `fromString` from that instance to turn it into the type it's supposed to be.

So you could do the same with:

```
countGoodsQuery :: Query
countGoodsQuery = fromString
            ( "select count('*')" ++
              "from table" ++
              "where ((acquisition_date <= ?)" ++
              "and ((sale_date is null) or " ++
              "(sale_date < ?)))" )
```

(And `(++)` doesn't work on `IsString a`, only `String`, so it forced your type back down to `String`.)

Comment: Yep, if you explicitly use `fromString` yourself you won't need `OverloadedStrings`.